# Console rPogram and Assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net

When I use Visual Studio to create a C# console application, I can readily use the `Console` class since it's defined in the `System` namespace (`mscorlib` assembly). I am assuming the reference to mscorlib is added in the `machine.config` file.

However, in VS, I can see that some more references are also added automatically in the `*.csproj` file(like System.Core and System.Data). Why didn't Microsoft add these references to `machine.config` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, mscorlib is required it's such a integral part of .Net it has System.Object etc.   However if you don't have a need for database access you can just remove the System.Data from your references in your console application.